# Bubblesort sort duplicates into distinct list based on count

Tags: java, list, count, distinct, bubble-sort

I have a project for school but I need some hints.

I have an ArrayList that looks like such:

```
[0] Document 1
[1] Document 1
[2] Document 2
[3] Document 3
[4] Document 3
[5] Document 3
[6] Document 4
```

I need to use Bubblesort to get a distinct list that looks like this (sorted by the number of occurences each document had in the original list):

```
[0] Document 3
[1] Document 1
[2] Document 2
[3] Document 4
```

I'm free to create a new ArrayList or  use one external for-loop for finishing it up - but it needs to be sorted by Bubblesort.

I've created other implementations that create a distinct lists based on certain properties of each document - but now when faced with the number of times each document occcurs in the list I'm at a loss to a clean solution.

Edit: Here's the implementation I used for the other parts of the assignment ("attribute" is similar to "document" in my question above)

```
int r = attributes.size() - 1;
    boolean swapped = true;
    while(swapped && r >= 0) {
        swapped = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            Attributes current = attributes.get(i);
            Attributes next = attributes.get(i + 1);
            if(current.occurrence > next.occurrence) {
                swapped = true;
                attributes.set(i, next);
                attributes.set(i + 1, current);
            }
        }
        r--;
    }
```

Comment: But the purpose of a bubble sort is to sort stuff by an order.  Why are the dos out of order in your output?

Comment: Sorry it might have been unclear so I edited orignial. The new list is sorted by number of occurences in the first list. Since 3 is in the original list three times it has the highest count.

Comment: ok so you have to use a bubble sort (of your own creation?) to sort occurrences of document objects in your array list by frequency, biggest to smallest?  Do you have any code for what you have tried?

Comment: Edited the originial post with the code I've used for the other problems in the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a boilerplate example, you can use something like this.

```
List<Integer> arrList = Arrays.asList( 5, 0, 0, 2 );
    int freq = Collections.frequency(arrList, "0);

       System.out.println("Frequency of '0' is: "+freq);    
       }
```

Comment: Since OP is not allowed to use standard sort, I very much doubt that he is allowed to use `Collections.frequency`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ha well yes I suppose that is true.

Comment: This solved it cleanly, in my inner loop I was able to use this statement:

if(Collections.frequency(documents, current.document) < Collections.frequency(documents, next.document))